# Include null/0 rows in a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to query a database for users and the the amount of time they spent on each Activity Category. These categories are stored in the table ActivityCategory (int Id, varchar Name). There's only 8 of them and I want to see all of them, even when **nobody** spent time on a specific category.

I have the following query:

```
select u.NoEmploye, u.FirstName, u.LastName, Total=sum(h.NbHeures), ac.Name
from Users u
join Semaines s on u.EntityGuid=s.UserGuid
join HeuresProjets hp on s.Id=hp.WeekId
join Heures h on hp.HPId=h.HpGuid
join ActivityCodes code on h.Code=code.ActivityId
join ActivityCategory ac on code.Categorie=ac.Id
group by u.NoEmploye, u.FirstName, u.LastName, ac.Name
order by u.NoEmploye
```

It works fine but it doesn't return unused ActivityCategories. I tried every combination of full/left/right/inner/outer/you-name-it joins. The best I could get is completely null rows when a category is used by nobody and a null ac.Name for categories a specific user doesn't use but others do. I suspect the `group by [...]`*`ac.Name`* part is what's "eating" the unused categories. What am I doing wrong? Should I write a select query the a second one to group the results? I'll have a dozen more similar queries to write so I'd like to understand instead of just having a fixed query with no explanation.

**EDIT** 
Lamak's second query works so far but it has the same problem when I add a where clause.

**EDIT2** ypercube' edit works perfectly

Now let's see if I understand the query correctly.
I coalesce the Sum with 0 to have a proprer value when the result would be null. I start the selection from ActivityCategory to make sure I have all of them, even the unused ones, which I cross join with users to have every combination of ActivityCategory and Users. I left join Activitycodes to only get relevant rows and then I inner join my other tables to get to Semaine. My condition are applied to the Semaine table's join because I want to filter my data before the cross join. Finally, I group my data by Users and ActivityCategory to have the sum works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT  u.NoEmploye, u.FirstName, u.LastName, Total=sum(h.NbHeures), ac.Name
FROM ActivityCategory ac
LEFT JOIN ActivityCodes code
    ON code.Categorie=ac.Id
LEFT JOIN Heures h
    ON h.Code=code.ActivityId
LEFT JOIN HeuresProjets hp
    ON hp.HPId=h.HpGuid
LEFT JOIN Semaines s
    ON s.Id=hp.WeekId
LEFT JOIN Users u
    ON u.EntityGuid=s.UserGuid
GROUP BY u.NoEmploye, u.FirstName, u.LastName, ac.Name
ORDER BY u.NoEmploye
```

Basically, if you want all Categories, you need to use that table as the first table on your `FROM` and do `LEFT JOIN`s to that table.

**UPDATE**
If you want every category for every user on your results, you'll need a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT  u.NoEmploye, u.FirstName, u.LastName, Total=sum(h.NbHeures), ac.Name
FROM ActivityCategory ac
CROSS JOIN Users u
LEFT JOIN ActivityCodes code
    ON code.Categorie=ac.Id
LEFT JOIN Heures h
    ON h.Code=code.ActivityId
LEFT JOIN HeuresProjets hp
    ON hp.HPId=h.HpGuid
LEFT JOIN Semaines s
    ON s.Id=hp.WeekId AND u.EntityGuid=s.UserGuid
GROUP BY u.NoEmploye, u.FirstName, u.LastName, ac.Name
ORDER BY u.NoEmploye
```

To solve the issue when you want to add a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT  u.NoEmploye, u.FirstName, u.LastName, 
        Total=COALESCE(SUM(h.NbHeures),0), ac.Name
FROM ActivityCategory ac
CROSS JOIN Users u
LEFT JOIN 
        ActivityCodes code
        JOIN Heures h
            ON h.Code=code.ActivityId
        JOIN HeuresProjets hp
            ON hp.HPId=h.HpGuid
        JOIN Semaines s
            ON s.Id=hp.WeekId 
            AND (some condition on the dates)            -- add here
    ON  ac.Id = code.Categorie
    AND u.EntityGuid = s.UserGuid
GROUP BY u.NoEmploye, u.FirstName, u.LastName, ac.Name
ORDER BY u.NoEmploye
```

Comment: Your logic seems right but when I run your query, sql server returns 8 rows (1 for each category) with null user data

Comment: 8 rows in addition to the results I mean. And users still don't  have a row for unused categories

Comment: @fhlamarche Ok. I think that you'll need to post some sample data and expected results for me (and other users) to provide a better answer.

Comment: You need to do a cross join to achieve what you want. However, your database structure is too complex to replicate (I'm lazy). I suggest you create a SQLFiddle item and send over the link. I can code your sql from there.

Comment: @fhlamarche In the results, do you want a row for every combination of `User` and `ActivityCategory`?

Comment: @ypercube Yes, that's what I want. It will end up in a report and every category must be there as well as every user.

Comment: @RobertCo lemme look into this

Comment: may need to sum(coalesce(h.NbHeures,0)) not sure if SQL server handles null values as 0 when doing the sums.

Comment: @Lamak thanks, this works. And I'm almost done. Your query does work but as I said to ypercube, this data will be used in a report. More precisely, with a start and end date coming from Semaines s. Should I accept this answer and create another question or do we continue here?

Comment: oops, I just noticed I missed a part. Adding a where clause returns us back to square 1